# Zend passing value to function

Tags: zend-framework

I written a function in model:

```
public function plan_values($id)
{
    echo $id;
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select = $db->select()
              ->from(array('h'=>'hosted_site_content'),array('h.hsc_value','h.hsc_plan'))
            ->joinLeft(array('m'=>'hosted_plan_content_mapping'),'h.hsc_type=m.hpcm_type_id')
            ->where('m.hpcm_type_id="'.$id.'"')
            ->order('h.hsc_plan asc');

    $row = $db->fetchAll($select);



    if (!$row) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
    return $row;
}
```

and written its controller as follow:

```
$planvalues = new Application_Model_DbTable_PlanList();
$this->view->planview = $planvalues->plan_values($id);
```

how can I pass the value to the variable in view?
    $this->planview(4);
this is not giving the answer. it showing only the 4th array element of out put. Is I miss anything? Please help. I have to pass the '4' value to the function plan_values.

Comment: where does you "4" come from? your question is incomplete, the code looks fine. you can access the row array inside your view via `$this->planview[index]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `4` has already been used/consumed in the call to:

```
$planvalues->plan_values($id); // $id == 4, right?
```

Looks like your call to `$planvalues->plan_values($id)` should return an *array* of rows. 
You then assign this into the view as `$this->view->planview`. So in your view-script, `$this->planview` is precisely that array of row data. Iterate over the array to render them all.

If you want to display/use that `$id` value of 4 down in your view-script, then feel free to pass it along using `$this->view->id = $id` (in the controller) and then pick it up for us in the view-script using `$this->id`.

Comment: HI David, actually i have to pass the value of 4 from view to the controller. then this value of Id will pass to plan_values function and return the result based on the passing id value. how can i pass the value in view

Comment: Aaah, now I think I see what you mean. Sounds like one page has a link containing this id = 4. Then another page will display the results of calling `plan_values(4)`. If so, then the issue is how to render the link (with the id param) on the first page and how to pick up that id param on the receiving page. Short answer: The link is something like `<a href="/thecontroller/theaction/id/4">`. Then you pick up the param value in your receiving controller using `$id = $this->_getParam('id');`.

Comment: yes. but I am not doing this through url. I have another function. That function push a value based on some action. that push result I have to pull into this function. In that cases _getParam can't use. that is my problem

Comment: That other action returns a number? No layout? No page rendering? Sounds like you need to refactor the processing of that action into a component that you can consume in that action and in the action of your question.